# Split math expression?

Tags: c#, regex

I wanna write calculation software,for separate numbers from operators i used Regex.Matches().but there is a bug that i displayed with used of image. In addition,math expression is :

> 5*10-18/(3+19)

```
    public class Tokenization
{
    public string MathExpression { get; set; }

    public Tokenization(string expression)
    {
        MathExpression = expression;
    }

    public List<string> MathExpressionParser()
    {
        int number;
        List<string> tokenList = new List<string>();
        List<string> tL = new List<string>();

        var numbersAndOperators = Regex.Matches(MathExpression, "(['*,+,/,-,),(']+)|([0-9]+)");

        foreach (var item in numbersAndOperators)
        {
            tokenList.Add(item.ToString());
            Debug.WriteLine(item.ToString());
        }

        return tokenList;
    }
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: You can compute the result of the string `5*10-18/(3+19)` without doing all of this. If that is what you are after.

Comment: @user3185569,i don't use of compute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this expression:

```
string expr = "5*10-18/(3+19)";

foreach(var match in Regex.Matches(expr, @"([*+/\-)(])|([0-9]+)"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.ToString());
}
```

Result:

```
5
*
10
-
18
/
(
3
+
19
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `+`, since all the operators you match are single-char. Don't forget to escape `-`, it should be `\-`. Also there's no need in commas and quotes.

The result is:

```
([*+/\-)(])|([0-9]+)
```

Additionally, put `@` before the regex string so as to avoid excess escaping. Or, escape the `-` with double `\\`:

```
([*+/\\-)(])|([0-9]+)
```

Comment: but,i get an error: unrecognized escape sequence == > "\-"

Answer (score 0):

adding small improvement for decimal values.
update the reg-x with follow.

```
@"([*+/\-)(])|([0-9.]+|.)"
```